# how to change a private bool value c++

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm creating a program that simulates a door.
I have this problem with these booleans I set to be private but I want to change their value to be false when the program starts.
Also the cause I'm swedish I use the words klar = done and val = choice, bad habit of mine.

```
//Main.cpp contains the user menu for the "door" controls
#include <iostream>
#include "Door2.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    bool done = false;
    int val,klar;
    Door2* d= new Door2();
    while(done == false){

        cout << "Do you want to?" << endl;
        cout << "1. Open the door?" << endl;
        cout << "2. Close the door?" << endl;
        cout << "3. Lock the door?" << endl;
        cout << "4. Unlock the door?" << endl;

        cin >> val;

        if (val == 1){
            d->open();
        }
        if (val == 2){
            d->close();
        }
        if (val == 3){
            d->lock();
        }
        if (val == 4){
            d->unlock();
        }

        cout << "Är du klar?" << endl << "1. Ja!" << endl << "2.Nej!" << endl;
        cin >> klar;

        if(klar == 1){
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now here in the header file is where I have the two booleans, is there any way to set their value to false when the program starts?

```
#pragma once

class Door2{

private:
    bool Open;
    bool Lock;
public:
    void open();
    void close();
    void lock();
    void unlock();
};
```

And the Door.cpp

```
//Door.cpp The file that checks if the "door" is closed open locked unlocked etc.
#include "Door2.h" 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Door2::open(){
    if (Open == true){
         cout << "The door is already open!" << endl;
    }else{
    Open = false;
    cout << "The door is open!" << endl;
}
}
void Door2::close(){
    if (Open == false){
        cout << "The door is already closed!" << endl;
    }else{
        Open = true;
        cout << "The door is closed!" << endl;
    }
}
void Door2::lock(){
    if (Lock == true){
         cout << "The door is already locked!" << endl;
    }else{
        Lock = false;
        cout << "The door is locked!" << endl; 
    }

}

void Door2::unlock(){

    if(Lock== false){
        cout << "The door is already unlocked!" << endl;
    }else{
        Lock = true;
        cout << "The door is unlocked!" << endl;
    }

}
```

Edit: I'm new to classes in c++ and yes I've tried to look for an answer but could not find any.

Comment: you need to 'initialize' the values `Open` and `Lock`.. Read about constructors in c++ to achieve it..

Comment: and please don't do `if (thing == true)` or `if (thing == false)`. They're booleans. Use `if (thing)` or `if (! thing)` as appropriate

Comment: I'll try to remember that, it's just that I got explained to do so in the programming class I had last year.

Comment: try to avoid using pointers unless it is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't set these variables at program start, but when the Door object is constructed:

.h

```
class Door {
   // ....
   Door(); // Constructor
```

.cpp

```
Door::Door() : open (false), Lock(false) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a **constructor** with an initializer list that sets your flags to `false` :

```
Door2() : Open(false), Lock(false) { }
```

**Note :**

You should put your types in dedicated namespaces and avoid putting then in the global one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Constructor 
       Door()
       {
        open=false;
        lock=false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a constructor, this will set the values when the door is declared. 
At the moment I see you are using the default constructor, but you can replace that simply as in the answers that just appeared. 
Either way, I suggest going through the classes/constructors tutorials again.